# Canonical way of using poll on file descriptors that require additional attributes

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm using `poll` to handle events on various file descriptors for a program of mine. Each connection has certain properties that go along with it. It requires a session identifier as well as a target file descriptor (separate from the fd being processed by `poll`).

Here is what the struct looks like:

```
typedef struct
{
    struct pollfd pfd;
    uint32_t session_id;
    int target_fd;
} my_conn;
```

Now, `poll` accepts an array of `struct pollfd` objects. Now, of course a `my_conn*` will degrade to a `struct pollfd*`, but since `poll` does not accept an array of pointers, I cannot simply use a `my_conn**` aligned by the first attribute.

My initial reaction is to iterate through the `my_conn` array and handle each file descriptor with a timeout of zero.

```
my_conn *conns = /* initialize connections*/ ;
size_t my_conn_count = /* number of connections */;

size_t i;
int cnt;
for(i = 0; i < my_conn_count; ++i)
{
    cnt = poll(&conns[i].pfd, 1, 0);
    if(cnt > 0)
    {
        // handle event
    }
}
```

My question is this: is there a better way to handle file descriptors that have additional attributes? Some type of `map` would work, but it seems that it would be more memory intensive. Does running `poll` with a timeout of 0 have a noticeable performance decrease over `poll`-ing multiple file descriptors at once?

Comment: Pretty much *anything* would be better than the approach you present.  By polling for each file descriptor's readiness separately and serially, you completely defeat the purpose of using `poll()` in the first place.

Comment: I don't see how it "defeats the purpose" given that it is still non-blocking and allows me to determine when the fd is readable/writable. Is that not the purpose of `poll()`?

Comment: Yes, even though it has a non-blocking timeout.  Better than a non-blocking poll of one file descriptor at a time would be to simply attempt a non-blocking read or write on the file descriptor, as appropriate, and cut `poll()` out of the picture altogether.

Comment: So how can I remedy this? Just have some sort of map that relates the desired fd to its other attributes?

Comment: In fact, Goodies, yes, that is pretty much what I would suggest.  I'm in the middle of writing it up as an answer.

Comment: Building a new list for poll or select on every call to poll is trivial compared to the cost of the poll system call itself. Unless you have a very large number of file descriptors in which case you should be using epoll or similar functionality.

Comment: It should be noted that this was simplified because it’s a part of a larger project that has no networking yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is this: is there a better way to handle file descriptors
>   that have additional attributes?

Yes.  I would have to put significant effort into devising a plausible alternative to your approach that would be worse.  If you have multiple file descriptors to test, then it defeats the purpose of `poll()` to poll them separately, whether in blocking or non-blocking mode.  With respect to your specific proposal, you would achieve the same thing more simply by cutting `poll()` out of the picture and performing non-blocking I/O directly.

> Some type of map would work, but it
>   seems that it would be more memory intensive.

Not necessarily.  You already have an array of `my_conn`.  If you construct a parallel array of `struct pollfd` then you have a direct correspondence between the two by index.  You probably then don't need `my_conn.pfd` to be a `struct pollfd`, as that's now external; all you need for that member is the (`int`) file descriptor itself -- if even that.  So the file descriptor gets duplicated, maybe, but that's it.  This is the approach I would recommend for the problem as presented.

> Does running `poll` with
>   a timeout of 0 have a noticeable performance decrease over `poll`-ing
>   multiple file descriptors at once?

I don't know how noticeable it would be in your case, but function calls are among the most expensive things you can do.  But it gets worse.  A typical application using `poll()` puts a loop around it in order to keep feeding data to or reading data from whichever file descriptors are ready at any given time.  It looks like you're setting up for that kind of thing, though I can't be sure.  If that is indeed what it boils down to, then using non-blocking `poll`s, whether one-for-all or not, makes that overall construct a busy loop, which is another of the things `poll()` is designed to avoid.